# Flash показ новой камеры

Tags: javascript

Есть список web-камер [ipcam](http://www.websint.ru/test/)  необходимо при нажатии новой камеры выполнялась функция:

```
   function getValue(camid){
    var test = document.getElementById("jwplayer").innerHTML='<object' + 
    'id="jwplayer" width="512" height="384" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" name="jwplayer" data="/media/js/player.swf">' +
    '<param name="allowfullscreen" value"true">' +
    '<param name="allowscriptaccess" value"always">' +
    '<param name="flashvars" value="file=' + 
    '<param name="flashvars" value="file='+camid+'&streamer=rtmp://188.65.51.172/&autostart=true">' + 
    '</object>'
    alert(test)}
```

Через alert вижу что обрабатывает функция а картинка новая не вырисовывается. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Жеско попробуй в хтмл без жаба скрипта. Вырисовывается?

Comment: если без js то все показывает.

Answer (score 1):

Заверните jwplayer в какой-нибудь div, ему поставьте id и через него меняйте его содержимое,
сейчас у вас получается `<object>` внутри `<object>`.